# Why is this code acting as if it is stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: python, list, nested-loops

I'm trying to create entries (1000), and I'm starting with the name. I came up with some names, and I planned to copy  the entry with the number 0-9 added to to create more unique names. So I used a for loop inside of a for loop. Is it not possible to change the index into a string and add it to the end of the item in the list.

I thought about incrementing, because I have been coding a lot in C++ lately, but that didn't work because you don't need to increment when you use python's range function. I thought about changing the order of the loops

```
name = ['event', 'thing going on', 'happening', 'what everyones talkin', 'that thing', 'the game', 'the play', 'outside time', 'social time', 'going out', 'having fun']
```

```
for index in range(10): 
    for item in name:
        name.append(item+str(index))
return name
```

I want it to print out `['event0', 'thing going on1', ... 'having fun10']`

Thank you!

Comment: You are appending new item to the list on which you are iterating over. So the iteration will continue indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension

- [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) - method adds a counter to an iterable and returns it in a form of enumerate object.

**Ex.**

```
name = ['event', 'thing going on', 'happening', 'what everyones talkin', 'that thing', 'the game', 'the play', 'outside time', 'social time', 'going out', 'having fun']
new_list = [x+str(index) for index,x in enumerate(name)]
print(new_list)
```

**O/P:**

```
['event0', 'thing going on1', 'happening2', 'what everyones talkin3', 'that thing4', 'the game5', 'the play6', 'outside time7', 'social time8', 'going out9', 'having fun10']
```

Answer (score 0):

use a new list and append there:

```
newName = []
for index in range(10): 
    for item in name:
        newName.append(item+str(index))
return newName
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work as you expect:

```
name = ['event', 'thing going on', 'happening', 'what everyones talkin', 'that thing', 
'the game', 'the play', 'outside time', 'social time', 'going out', 'having fun']
for index in range(10): 
    name[index] = name[index]+str(index)
print (name)
```

**Output:**

```
['event0', 'thing going on1', 'happening2', 'what everyones talkin3', 'that thing4', 'the game5', 'the play6', 'outside time7', 'social time8', 'going out9', 'having fun10']
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding more elements to the list every time you run through the loop. Make a new empty list and append the elements to that list. That way your initial list stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

The inner for loop is appending new element to the array.

You simply need

```
for index in range(10): 
    name[index] = name[index] + str(index)
```

now your array contains your expected output. This changes your original array btw. If you want it to keep unchanged, then do the following.

```
newArray = []
for index in range(10): 
        newArray [index] = name[index] + str(index)
```